# Определение количества повторений строки с помощью вложенного цикла

Tags: java, циклы

Есть коллекция, которая содержит порядка 16000 строк, некоторые из них пустые, некоторые строки повторяются. Необходимо вывести на экран 
имя строк и количество их совпадений. Вариаций строк около 100

например:

> Пустая строка: 6543
>
> Строка Мама: 2340
>
> Строка Папа: 2311

Я знаю, что это делается с помощью вложенного цикла, но ничего не выходит.

```
ArrayList<String> datalist = new ArrayList<String>();
    datalist = GatewaySQL.getSQLfieldData();

   for (int i = 0;  i < datalist.size(); i++) {
        for (int x = 1; x < datalist.size() - 1; x++) { //сравниваем 1ый элемент с последующими
           if (datalist.get(i).equals(datalist.get(x))) { 
              comCount++;
               datalist.remove(x); // если я правильно понимаю, то повтор следует удалять
      ........
       }
   }
```

Comment: Что именно не выходит? ход мыслей правильный

Comment: C этой реализацией выходит ошибка размера списка, например. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 246, Size: 246

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Организуем новую коллекцию, в которой ключ - имя повторяющегося элемента, значение - количество повторений.

Пробегаемся по коллекции и считываем по ключу. Get вернет количество значений, с данным ключом. Перезаписываем значение в колеекции с тем же ключом, но со значением `count` больше на 1.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String temp : list) {
    Integer count = map.get(temp);
    map.put(temp, (count == null) ? 1 : count + 1);
}

 printMap(map);
```

чтоб вывести мапу (метод `printMap(map)`):

```
public static void printMap(Map<String, Integer> map){
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Строка: " + entry.getKey() + ", Повторений: " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

---

Вообще у класса `Collections` есть метод `frequency()`, который уже возвращает число дубликатов. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>(list); // в конструктор кладем наш список
for (String key : unique) {
    System.out.println("Строка: " + key + ", Повторений: " + Collections.frequency(list, key));
}
```

Однако на сколько он быстр (с учетом 16000 строк), я не в куРРРсе. 
Можете попробовать сравнить время выполнения его и другого метода.

Comment: Спасибо! Скажите, возможно ли решить задачу с помощью вложенного цикла?

Comment: @РоманDriveMind да, вполне. @post_zeew в принципе что-то накидал в другом ответе, можно подглядеть..... я дополнил ответ с методом `frequency` класса `Collections`. Можете попробовать на досуге позапускать методы, посмотреть, что работает быстрее с таким объемом данных.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Потестил интереса ради на файле из 3M строк, Ваше решение работает за миллисекунды, мое – чуть более 10 минут %).

Comment: @post_zeew я скорее имел в виду тест первого варианта из моего ответа и `Collections.frequency`  xD

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, вместе с компиляцией 16000 строк обработалось меньше чем за 2 секунды.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант, предложенный [@Алексей Шиманский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/595549/220996) является более рациональным, но для полноты картины и для того чтобы показать, что в **теории** возможно сделать и так, как хотели Вы, еще один вариант:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "1", "4", "3", "1", "2", "3", "7", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4"));

for (int i=0; arrayList.size() != 0;) {
    String currentString = arrayList.get(i);
    int count = 0;
    Iterator<String> iterator = arrayList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        if (currentString.equals(iterator.next())) {
            iterator.remove();
            count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(currentString + ": " + count);
    if (count == 1) {
        i++;
    }
}
```

---

```
1: 3
2: 2
4: 2
3: 7
7: 1
```

Но для **практических** задач этот вариант недопустим.

Answer (score 1):

С java 8 можно использовать метод `Map.merge`:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "s", "s", "d", "d", "d", "f", "f", "g", "re", "r", "re", "g");
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
strings.forEach( s -> map.merge(s, 1, Integer::sum));
```

Либо через `Collectors.toMap`:

```
Map<String, Integer> collect = strings.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), s -> 1, Integer::sum));
```