# Какие циклы задать для обработки нескольких значений?

Tags: java, строки, циклы, foreach, условия

Задача в следующем: есть файл s.csv ( во вложении и скриншот ), нужно получить количество раз, где встречается слово VAG и сумму чисел из колонки 'С' по слову VAG. Вообщем все получилось, только я **НЕ ПОНИМАЮ, как задать циклы , чтобы автоматом посчитать еще по слову AND и другими словами, если их будет не две а десятки**. Прошу показать на моем коде куда вбить циклы. Я полагаю, что должен быть массив String[]str={Vag,And}, который через for each в метод data.contains() прогоняет, но дальше темный лес.

```html
package NewPhoneProj;
 
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
 
public class CSV {
 
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        String FileName = "c:\\TestJava\\s.csv";
 
        File file = new File(FileName);
 
        try {
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
 
            int sum = 0;
 
            int sumOfnum = 0;
 
            while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
                String data = inputStream.next();
 
                    if (data.contains("Vag"))
                       {
                    String[] values = data.split(";");
                    int numbers = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);
                    sum += numbers;
                    sumOfnum++;
                    
 
 
                }
            }
            inputStream.close();
            System.out.println("Sum: "+sum);
            System.out.println("SumOfnum: "+sumOfnum);
 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
 
        }
 
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тебе надо использовать `HashMap<String, Integer>`  где String - слово, Integer - подсчет количества.......... типа такого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/595549/191482 .... только со своей обработкой

Comment: Уважаемый Алексей, а 1) HashMap Вы советуете вставить прямо в качестве обработчика потока из файла или в качестве обработчика после того как данные будут загружены в какой-нибудь список? 2) Циклы и условия  не нужны дополнительные?

Comment: ничего не понял)) Объявляешь мапу (например с именем `wordsMap`) там же, где и `File file/String FileName`.... далее в цикле `while` у тебя идет  разбиение по сепаратору и проверка  `String[] values = data.split(";"); if (wordsMap.containsKey(values[0])) { ТУТ_СЛОЖЕНИЕ_В_МАПЕ_С_ДАННЫМ_СЛОВОМ значения с  values[2]  } else { ТУТ_ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ_В_МАПУ_СЛОВА и первоначальное значение  values[2] }`

Comment: Я буду тебе не по детски благодарен, если ты скорректируешь мой код согласно твоей рекомендации.   Хоть убейся не могу в голову представить.  Можно на конкретно примере показать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю дополнительный класс `WordInfo` с информацией о слове. А также `Map<String, WordInfo>`, в которой будет она содержаться. В итоге при пробегании в цикле смотрим, если в мапе есть слово - то прибавляем `count` и добавляем значение в `sum`, если еще нет - добавляем в мапу с инициализированными значениями.

```
class WordInfo {
    public int count = 1;
    public int sum;
    public WordInfo(int sum){
        this.sum = sum;
    }
}
```

main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    String FileName = "c:\\TestJava\\s.csv";

    File file = new File(FileName);
    Map<String, WordInfo> wordInfoMap = new HashMap<>();

    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);

        String[] values; String wordName; Integer wordSum;
        while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
            values = inputStream.next().split(";");
            wordName = values[0];
            wordSum = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);

            if (wordInfoMap.containsKey(wordName)) {
                wordInfoMap.get(wordName).count++;
                wordInfoMap.get(wordName).sum += wordSum;
            } else {
                wordInfoMap.put(wordName, new WordInfo(wordSum));
            }
        }

        inputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    // Итог:
    WordInfo wordInfo;
    for (Map.Entry<String, WordInfo> wordInfoEntry : wordInfoMap.entrySet()) {
        wordInfo = wordInfoEntry.getValue();
        System.out.println("Word \"" + wordInfoEntry.getKey() 
                            + "\". Count: "+ wordInfo.count 
                            + ",  Sum: " + wordInfo.sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну что же, огромное спасибо всем безразличным, а особенная благодарность Алексею за терпение и трудолюбие!

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan если ответ помог - можно жмакать стрелку вверх и ставить галку)

Comment: галку поставил, но вот рейтинг поднять не дает, типо не дорос до этого еще)

Comment: Алексей, попробовал тоже самое с другим файлом не получилось. Вот файл , соответственно поменял  в массиве значения   wordName = values[10];
            wordSum = Integer.parseInt(values[17]);  Пишет ошибку:   Фото файла https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/11/4/f2cc7cc78f326b452ac5f0af05493062-full.png        Вот фото  компилятора :  https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/11/4/f29e2564c22e36c7229a68fa2cd30386-full.png

Comment: Подскажи, пожалуйста, если не трудно

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan на самом деле я бы мог тебе пока порекомендовать прочитать вот это [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701409/191482), включить отладчик и посмотреть что у тебя находится в значениях....Это самый верный способ определять что у тебя не так в коде..... и еще хочу заметить, что т.к. в первой строке находятся заголовки столбцов, то первую итерацию минимум надо пропустить, иначе `Integer.parseInt` может не распарсить

Comment: Я выяснил, что проблема в  сепараторе (в разделителях слов). Т.е, если в слове сделан пробел или определенные иероглифы , то возникает ошибка. Теперь вопрос как правильно построить сепаратор values = inputStream.next().split(";");   Видимо кроме точки с запятой требуется  еще что-то ((

Comment: Если быть точнее, то проблема в регулярном выражении.  Мне нужно , чтобы фильтр игнорировал все, кроме точки с запятой ;

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan лучше создай еще один вопрос конкретно с данной проблемой. Глядишь быстрее ответ кто-то напишет, чем я)

Answer (score 0):

Вот код который возвращает по каждому уникальному значению первой колонки соответствующую сумму.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String FileName = "//home//dd//q.csv";

    File file = new File(FileName);

    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);

        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
            String data = inputStream.next();
            String[] values = data.split(";");
            if (map.get(values[0])==null) {
                map.put(values[0], Integer.parseInt(values[2]));
            } else {
                map.put(values[0], Integer.parseInt(values[2]) + map.get(values[0]));
            }

        }
        inputStream.close();

        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key + " " + map.get(key));
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Comment: И тебе спасибо добрый человек. Буду анализировать и укреплять знания.